# How to allow Pure-FTPD to write to another user's directory

Tags: virtualhost, ftp

I have set up the following stack: Nginx, php-fpm and Pure-FTPD on a debian 6.

In order for PHP-FPM pools to run under each different user I have created a system user for each website I host under `/var/www`;

I have set up pure-ftpd with mysql virtual users support (pure-ftpd-mysql). It works and I can read the files under `/var/www/example.com` . However I can't write or edit anything because they're owned by the Example user.

I know a possible solution would be to have **775** permissions for `/var/www/example.com` (pure-ftpd's user and Example user are in the same group), but I don't want it this way... .

So is there another (possibly better way) to have pure-ftpd's user full access to  `/var/www/example.com/` and `/var/www/example-2.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Posix ACLs?

Comment: would you mind expanding a bit on how posix acls can help in this situation ?

Comment: well, I was thinking to achive some cPanel-like functionality, but avoiding as much as possible setuids and such, as I consider it a possible security threat. Thanks for sharing your knowledge, I'll take a look at your suggestion.